# How to replace multiple slashes (///) in a string to one slash (/) in Go lang?

Tags: go

**Input string:** "///hello//stackover.flow"

**Expected output:** "/hello/stackover.flow"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an option. You can use it if you need to replace some other multiple characters.

```
re, _ := regexp.Compile("/+")

fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllLiteralString("///hello//stackover.flow", "/"))
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`path.Clean`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/#Clean) for that.

> ```
> func Clean(path string) string
> ```
>
> Clean returns the shortest path name equivalent to path by purely lexical processing. It applies the following rules iteratively until no further processing can be done:
>
> 1. Replace multiple slashes with a single slash.
> 2. Eliminate each . path name element (the current directory).
> 3. Eliminate each inner .. path name element (the parent directory)
>      along with the non-.. element that precedes it.
> 4. Eliminate .. elements that begin a rooted path:
>      that is, replace "/.." by "/" at the beginning of a path.
>      The returned path ends in a slash only if it is the root "/".
>
> If the result of this process is an empty string, Clean returns the string ".".

And here's a simple benchmark which compares it with regexp solution:

```
package main

import (
    "path"
    "regexp"
    "testing"
)

var p = "///hello//stackover.flow"

func BenchmarkPathRegexp(b *testing.B) {
    re := regexp.MustCompile("/+")
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        re.ReplaceAllLiteralString(p, "/")
    }
}

func BenchmarkPathClean(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        path.Clean(p)
    }
}
```

Results:

```
BenchmarkPathRegexp-4        2000000           794 ns/op
BenchmarkPathClean-4        10000000           145 ns/op
```